# How to solve "ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I got table with two unique column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "users" (  
    "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,  
    "phone" varchar(20) UNIQUE,  
    "email" varchar(50) UNIQUE  
);
```

I want to write save or update method
My jooq code:

```java
dsl.insertInto(Users.USERS)
    .set(Users.USERS.EMAIL, user.getEmail())
    .set(Users.USERS.PHONE, user.getPhone())
    .onConflict(Users.USERS.PHONE, Users.USERS.EMAIL)
    .doNothing()
    .execute();
```

But i got exception:
"ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"
Help please.

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: @pringi 14.0-1.pgdg110+1

Answer (score 1):

The error says it correctly. You have specified an onConflict clause, but no existing unique index was found for it. You have 2 separated unique indices, but the onConflict specifies two columns. Your query would work if you had defined a single unique index on both phone and email together.

Solution 1: Adding a unique index over the 2 columns by `unique(phone, email)` should fix it (assuming you want to have the **combination** of the phone and email unique).

Solution 2: Make onConflict correspond to all the unique indexes. Consider using `onConflict().doNothing()` to do nothing for any constraint violation that can occur.

Comment: Thx for answer. Second solution is what i need but i don't understand how to implement it. Should i call the "onConflict()" method twice ? But jooq not allow to do this

Comment: Have you tried not specifying anything? Simply .onConflict().doNothing()?

Comment: It worked! But. If I still need to specify multiple unique columns. Pretend i have third column with unique constraint, but i do not want to include it in "onConflict" method

Comment: I think resolving conflicts differently for different columns is complicated. I do not know how to do it in a nice way. If you find something, please add or edit it here.